# Automatically generate sub-models for new OneToOne columns?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Say I have a Doctrine entity like so:

```php
#[ORM\Entity]
#[ORM\Table(name: 'product')]
class Product
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: DBALTYPES::INTEGER)]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    private int $id;
    #[ORM\Column(type: DBALTYPES::STRING, length: 50)]
    private string $sku;
    
    ...
}
```

I update the DB to match, and it goes into production. Now imagine I want to add a new OneToOne column, like so:

```php
#[ORM\Entity]
#[ORM\Table(name: 'product')]
class Product
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: DBALTYPES::INTEGER)]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    private int $id;
    #[ORM\Column(type: DBALTYPES::STRING, length: 50)]
    private string $sku;
    #[ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity: Attribute::class)]
    private Attribute $name;
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = new Attribute();
    }
    
    ...
}
```

All existing `Product`s were created before the `$name` property was added, so updating the DB adds the `name_id` column but leaves it defaulted to `null`. This is a problem because `$name` is a non-nullable property but it will be undefined except for newly-created products.

Is there a way to have Doctrine generate the required sub-models automatically when updating the DB with `orm:schema-tool:update`? Or do I have to do this manually somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you create a migration `console make:mig`

```php
final class Version20230613081942 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function getDescription(): string
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function up(Schema $schema): void
    {
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->addSql('UPDATE product SET name = (SELECT id FROM attribute LIMIT 1) WHERE name IS NULL;');
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema): void
    {
        // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->addSql('UPDATE product SET name = NULL');
    }
}
```

Adding an index to that column will also make the update faster

```php
#[ORM\Table(indexes: new Index(name: 'index_name', columns: ['attribute_id']))]
```

Comment: Indeed, this is the solution. I wish Doctrine's documentation had a little more high-level overview of the intended setup, but I got there in the end. Cheers for confirming!